# Vanilla JS event delegation (NOT A CLICK EVENT) that returns more than the document object

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I have been trying to figure out a good way to replicate the following code as vanilla JS without currying inside a document event listener. What is the way to make the following code below into a vanilla js event listener.

```
$(document).on('click', 'myElement', function(){
    //do something to myElement
});
```

Is there something like the above that would be similar to the below in theory

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
   if(event.target){
     // do something to myElement
   }
});
```

Please go to [Vanilla JS event delegation (NOT A CLICK EVENT) that returns more than the document object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38925544/vanilla-js-event-delegation-not-a-click-event-that-returns-more-than-the-docum) for the second part of accepted answer below.

Comment: Have you tried your theory?

Comment: The "dupicate" notice attached to this is not the same as my question. It is similar but the delegation is completely different. Be weary of the notice above.

I just could of worded this better.

Comment: To be completely honest, your current question is exactly the same as the duplicated (the way it is worded right now). Judging by the accepted answer, your question was "How can I know the HTML element of `event.target`?". As for future readers that would google this question, the duplicated answer would be better even if it doesn't suits you. Anyway, what matters is that you found your answer!

Comment: I have updated the question in hopes to clear some things up and unaccepted the answer. To avoid writing another post for duplication, but it really needs to be for the case scenario of something other than a click event, mousemove/mouseenter in this case. Something where the target can not be directly specified.

Comment: Reopened the question. As for your answer, use `mouseover` along with Dekel's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually what your jquery block does is listening for any click within the document, and when there is a click it checks if the element that was clicked is `<myElement>`.

You can do the same with a code that is similar to this:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        if(event.target.nodeName == 'myElement'.toUpperCase()) {
        // do something to myElement
    }
});
```

### Update

To have the answer up-to-date with the change of the question, I added an example to demonstrate the differences between `mouseover` and `mouseenter`:

> Works much better with snippet in full-screen mode

```js
document.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    console.log('mouseover '+ event.target.id);
    if(event.target.nodeName == 'myElement'.toUpperCase()) {
        // do something to myElement
    }
});

document.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(event) {
    console.log('mouseenter '+ event.target.id);
    if(event.target.nodeName == 'myElement'.toUpperCase()) {
        // do something to myElement
    }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
body > div {
  margin: 0;
}
div div {
  border-color: red;
}
div div div {
  border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer1"> Outer 1
  <div id="outer2"> Outer 2
    <div id="inner"> Inner </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that `mouseenter` event will fire **only once** (for the `document` object) while the `mouseover` event will fire for every change of element within the `document` (this will happen for **every** element in the dom tree).

> As for jQuery

The way jQuery overcome this behavior to make this

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', 'myElement',
```

work, is that they change the `mouseenter` event to `mouseover` (on the `document`) and they do internal checking to see if the event was a `mouseover` or `mouseenter` on `myElement`.

Comment: Hey that is correct, could you possibly expand on something for me though. Say it is not a click event but a mouseenter. How would you delegate that without the event just returning the document?

I probably should of put that in my example. But as far as the question your answer is correct.

Comment: @NicholasByDesign, is there a reason for un- accpeting my answer here?

Comment: Yes, it was technically correct to my situation that I had originally posted it was not what I had intended, along with some debate with admins on duplicates.  

I updated my question to be more specific. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @NicholasByDesign Then you should roll back your edit and accept this answer, but ask a new, separate question (possibly with a link back to this one if you want to refer to it). It is not fair to the answerers for you to edit your question so that their answers are no longer relevant.

Comment: @Paulpro Totally agree with you, but then again, this answer is still the good one if he explain the difference between `mouseover` and `mouseenter`. I'd definitely go for that since the "duplicate" would only be noise... Anyway, i gave him an upvote so he as a -5 instead of -15 :)

Comment: Answer updated with an example and explanation for how to work with `mouseover` and `mouseenter`

Comment: Please visit here if you want to submit your answer for the mouseenter/mousemove portion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38925544/vanilla-js-event-delegation-not-a-click-event-that-returns-more-than-the-docum

Comment: Your link is to this question. You sure this is what you meant?

Comment: to expand the usage of this sample code, you can also add inside the condition `.matches()` like so `if ( event.target.matches( 'myElement' ) )` the benefit of doing it this way is that inside matches you can pass anything you'd pass in `.querySelector()` such as `div.ClassName#Id[attr]`

Answer (score -2):

Here is a solution using plain JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("someId").addEventListener("click", doSomething);

function doSomething() {
    // whatever you like...
}
```

Comment: It's not equivalent. `on` will re-apply the event listener to any new elements that are added under the selector

Comment: I see... maybe this solution suffices anyway when he is not adding new elements dynamically.